# design pattern to share properties

Tags: c#, design-patterns, webforms

I have a class called `SignupForService`, which represents an application a user can submit to sign up for our service. It has many fields, some of them includes 'first name', 'last name'..

I have a different class that models a form that the user needs to fill out as part of that application. It has fields like 'first name, age, foo, bar...'. Let's called this class Form2

On `SignupForService2` I want to use the same FirstName as what is on the `SignupForService`. I want them to be totally linked to one another.

The best I can come up with is using Composition, but sending in a reference to the parent to the child class. Like this:

```
public class SignupForService2
{
   public SignupForService2(SignupForService parent)
   {
       _parent = parent;
   }
    private SignupForService _parent;
    public string FirstName 
    {
       get{
            return _parent.FirstName
          }
    }

    //more stuff here
}


public class SignupForService
{
     public string FirstName;
     public SignupForService2 signupForService2;
}
```

The reason why I don't just put the properties all on the SignupForService class is because it is getting way too bloated, and logically can be split into this `SignupForService2` (it is all or nothing for the fields). I also can't just inherit SignupForService in SignupForService2 because it has many fields that wouldn't make sense to have on SignupForService2. (I have other cases as well, such as SignupForService3,SignupForService4..)

Is there a design pattern that better solves this, or a name for this pattern that I'm not aware of and it can be described to me better? I want to know the pros/cons of this approach.

Thanks so much

Comment: Search for *binding*.

Comment: You might not want to redefine the Application class when working with WinForms or WPF; a new developer experienced in either will be confused when it isn't the WinForms/WPF class. (Just in case this example has some basis in reality)

Comment: @AustinSalonen, 'Application' and 'Form2' are just dumb classes that should have nothing to do with UI. Although in this case, I am binding them to an ASP.NET page

Comment: The terminology is incredibly confusing.  Please rename the classes in the example. Please tag if this is webforms or MVC or other.  I would never have guessed this was an ASP.NET application.  Which design patterns to recommend are definitely impacted by the underlying technology.  Event driven applications have a totally different set of patterns than stateless web applications.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek when I google for 'binding design pattern' I only get results for MVVM. I am using ASP.NET WebForms, however my question I was hoping was not UI specific...

Comment: You can add an MVC project to ASP.NET webforms.  Focus new development efforts towards the new framework.  Let the old code pass away naturally.  http://blogs.ibs.com/Scott.Zischerk/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20

Comment: Redundant structure for data-transfer objects (models) is acceptable.  Redundant functionality is what should be avoided.

Comment: Not to be condescending but maybe you need to read up more on general OO design? For a start it is seldom a good practice to just add a number to existing class names. Think about what the purpose of each class is and name it appropriately. And in your case, why don't you just pass the model between your service classes? That's what they're for. Reading up on MVC (the pattern not the framework) may help you.

Comment: For this i would prefer to go with singleton along with factory or abstract factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you are curious about how to do the things properly.

Try reading about MVC, MVVM, IoC, DI. This is quite a lot of reading and not the easiest to understand at the beginning but all of this somehow refers to the problem you are trying to solve.

Generally you will choose different approaches depending on whether you create WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Good advice but not an answer... should be in the comments section.